# Deserializing Json in "installments"

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

So let's say I have a model that I wanna fill with data, but not all of the data at once.

The model is:

```
public class SubPlayground
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("weekdays")]
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Weekdays { get; set; }
}

//Say here we want to populate the first two properties
var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubPlayground>(jsonString1);

//And here populate the third one without overriding the first two
m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubPlayground>(jsonString2);
```

Is there a workaround for this?

***Edit:*** For clarification: The two `jsonString`s are different, each one will contain only the corresponding properties. So that `jsonString1` will contain name and type while `jsonString2` will contain just weekdays.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more info on your requirements ... Do both JSON strings need contain all the properties in the JSON data or can they only contain the extra properties you want to load? Are both JSON strings the same or are they different? If they are different, how so?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying that. The two `jsonString`s are different, each one will contain only the corresponding properties. So that `jsonString1` will contain `name` and `type` while `jsonString2` will contain just `weekdays`.

Comment: Makes sense. Xiaoy's response would work well for you then. Can you please update your question to include this extra information so others searching understand how the PopulateObject method works?

Thanks!

Comment: Done! Thank you.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` to populate an existing object:

```
var jsonString1 = "{ Name: \"qwe\"}";
var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubPlayground>(jsonString1);

var jsonString2 = "{ Type: \"asd\"}";
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonString2, m);
```

Comment: ..well, that was easy.

Comment: Keep in mind though that if your JSON contains values for properties you have already set, this function will override those values you set earlier.